# Is it possible to roll back CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements in major SQL databases?

Tags: sql, transactions, ddl, create-table

I am working on a program that issues DDL. I would like to know whether `CREATE TABLE` and similar DDL can be rolled back in

- Postgres
- MySQL
- SQLite
- et al

Describe how each database handles transactions with DDL.

Comment: Just to complement this thread, [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) also doesn't support transactional DDL statements for most of SQL commands, according to [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#transaction_isolation).

Answer (score 178, accepted):

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis provides an overview of this issue from PostgreSQL's perspective.

Is DDL transactional according to this document?

- PostgreSQL - yes
- MySQL - no; DDL causes an implicit commit
- Oracle Database 11g Release 2 and above - by default, no, but an alternative called edition-based redefinition exists
- Older versions of Oracle - no; DDL causes an implicit commit
- SQL Server - yes
- Sybase Adaptive Server - yes
- DB2 - yes
- Informix - yes
- Firebird (Interbase) - yes

SQLite also appears to have transactional DDL as well. I was able to `ROLLBACK` a `CREATE TABLE` statement in SQLite. Its `CREATE TABLE` documentation does not mention any special transactional 'gotchas'.

Comment: However, the default Python driver for sqlite prevents transactional SQL. http://bugs.python.org/issue10740

Comment: So the answer is "Yes, they can be rolled back, unless you are using MySQL or older versions of Oracle."

Comment: No, there are other SQL databases besides the ones listed.

Comment: There are'nt any other "**major** SQL databases" :-)

Comment: There is an open issue in MariaDB for adding transactional DDL support: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-4259. Please vote for it.

Comment: The somewhat limited `ALTER TABLE` statement of SQLite is also able to be rolled back. It is not explicitly mentioned in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). What is mentioned there is how to perform "advanced" changes inside a transaction.

Comment: H2: no ("most data definition language (DDL) statements, such as "create table", commit the current transaction")

Comment: Note: SQL Server does **not** _fully_ support transactional DDL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191544(v=sql.105)

Answer (score 34):

PostgreSQL has transactional DDL for most database objects (certainly tables, indices etc but not databases, users). However practically any DDL will get an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the target object, making it completely inaccessible until the DDL transaction finishes. Also, not all situations are quite handled- for example, if you try to select from table `foo` while another transaction is dropping it and creating a replacement table `foo`, then the blocked transaction will finally receive an error rather than finding the new `foo` table. (Edit: this was fixed in or before PostgreSQL 9.3)

`CREATE INDEX ... CONCURRENTLY` is exceptional, it uses three transactions to add an index to a table while allowing concurrent updates, so it cannot itself be performed in a transaction.

Also the database maintenance command `VACUUM` cannot be used in a transaction.

Comment: I'd argue that if I try to select from table `foo` while another transaction is dropping and recreating it, then I an OK with the old version or error. I am not OK with the new version, because it was not committed yet, so I must not see it. I am OK with an error, because in concurrent transactional access one has to be prepared to restart transactions anyway. If errors happen more often than necessary it might reduce performance, but it is still correct.

Comment: @JanHudec: you won't see an uncommitted version of the new table, only the result of the entire transaction that dropped/recreated it. i.e. a transaction that drops, recreates and repopulates a table is effectively atomic wrt other processes selecting from that table. (but everything will get blocked as soon as they even try to read the table's schema)

Answer (score 8):

Can't be done with **MySQL** it seems, very dumb, but true... (as per the accepted answer)

> "The CREATE TABLE statement in InnoDB is processed as a single
>   transaction. This means that a ROLLBACK from the user does not undo
>   CREATE TABLE statements the user made during that transaction."

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Tried a few different ways and it simply won't roll back..

Work around is to simply set a failure flag and do "drop table tblname" if one of the queries failed..

Comment: Unfortunately as of v10.5,  MariaDB still doesn't support transactional DDL, see [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/start-transaction/#ddl-statements) for detail.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the other answers are pretty outdated.

As of 2019:

- Postgres has supported transactional DDL for many releases.
- SQLite has supported transactional DDL for many releases.
- MySQL has supported [Atomic DDL since 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/atomic-ddl.html) (which was released in 2018).

Comment: One should note that the Atomic DDL in MySQL 8 refers to merely atomic DDL statements, but not transactional statements. A DDL statement, atomic or not, mostly still causes implicit commit and thus cannot be executed within another transaction (e.g. `START TRANSACTION ... COMMIT;`. So you still cannot roll back DDL statements in a transaction if latter one in the same transaction fails. (see note under  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/atomic-ddl.html#atomic-ddl-characteristics)

Answer (score 4):

While it is not strictly speaking a "rollback", in Oracle the FLASHBACK command can be used to undo these types of changes, if the database has been configured to support it.