# What is supported as transactional in postgres

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I am trying find out what is postgres can handle safely inside of transaction, but I cannot find the relavant information in the [postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/index.html). So far I have found out the following:

- `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELTE` are fully supported inside transactions and rolled back when the transaction is not finished
- `DROP TABLE` is not handled safely inside a transaction, and is undone with a `CREATE TABLE`, thus recreates the dropped table but does not repopulate it
- `CREATE TABLE` is also not truly transactionized and is instead undone with a corresponding `DROP TABLE`

Is this correct? Also I could not find any hints as to the handling of `ALTER TABLE` and `TRUNCATE`. In what way are those handled and are they safe inside transactions? Is there a difference of the handling between different types of transactions and different versions of postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best I'm aware all of these commands are transaction aware, except for `TRUNCATE ... RESTART IDENTITY` (and even that one is transactional [since 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1.html).)

See the manual on [concurrency control](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) and [transaction-related commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-begin.html).

Answer (score 7):

`DROP TABLE` **is** transactional. To undo this, you need to issue a `ROLLBACK` not a `CREATE TABLE`. The same goes for `CREATE TABLE` (which is also undone using ROLLBACK).

`ROLLBACK` is always the only correct way to undo a transaction - that includes ALTER TABLE and TRUNCATE.

The only thing that is never transactional in Postgres are the numbers generated by a sequence (CREATE/ALTER/DROP SEQUENCE themselves **are** transactional though).

Comment: Yeah, i meant the way it is internally handled... Guess I just was confused by some answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692690/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-create-table-and-alter-table-statements-in-major-sql)

Comment: @LiKao: the answer in the linked question does not specifically talk about PostgreSQL. For a DBMS that does not support transactional DDL it is true that a DROP TABLE cannot only be "rolled back" by a CREATE TABLE.