# How to create foreign key only if it doesn't exists already?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

I have a table `common.client_contact` where I created foreign key using this code:

```
ALTER TABLE common.client_contact 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES common.contact_item(id);
```

If I execute this code, I will get several foreign keys with different names (like `client_contact_contact_id_fkey1`, `client_contact_contact_id_fkey2`, `client_contact_contact_id_fkey3` and so on).

So, before creating new constraint, I need to check if it's exists.

I check if this constraint exists in `pg_constraint` table:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_constraint WHERE conname = 'client_contact_contact_id_fkey'
```

And now I need to combine them together. Something like

```
IF NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM pg_constraint WHERE conname = 'client_contact_contact_id_fkey')
ALTER TABLE common.client_contact
    ADD CONSTRAINT client_contact_contact_id_fkey
    FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES common.contact_item(id)
```

or just

```
ALTER TABLE common.client_contact 
ADD FOREIGN KEY IF NOT EXISTS (contact_id) REFERENCES common.contact_item(id)
```

But these two queries are produce syntax error. So, how can I do it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use a `DO` block to execute it in PL/PgSQL.

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_constraint WHERE conname = 'client_contact_contact_id_fkey') THEN
        ALTER TABLE common.client_contact
            ADD CONSTRAINT client_contact_contact_id_fkey
            FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES common.contact_item(id);
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

You seem to be relying on the default constraint name generation, which isn't ideal. It's probably safer to use `information_schema` to check for the presence of a constraint that links the two columns.

The following query checks for a foreign key between the two tables without relying on the generated constraint name:

```
SELECT 1
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc 
INNER JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu 
  USING (constraint_catalog, constraint_schema, constraint_name) 
INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
  USING (constraint_catalog, constraint_schema, constraint_name) 
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
  AND ccu.table_name = 'contact_item' 
  AND ccu.table_schema = 'common'  
  AND ccu.column_name = 'contact_id' 
  AND tc.table_schema = 'common' 
  AND tc.table_name = 'client_contact'
  AND kcu.column_name = 'id';
```

Comment: BTW, I suspect the query above needs refining to make sure it doesn't match multicolumn constraints that *include* `contact_id` and `id`, so test further if you want to use it.

Comment: In the first part of code snippet, should it not be "IF NOT EXISTS" instead of "IF EXISTS"?

Comment: @KumarVaibhav Yes, yes it should. Fixing.

Comment: You can also use an exception handler instead of the if not exists. See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801919/postgres-add-constraint-if-it-doesnt-already-exist/32526723#32526723

Answer (score 11):

one way around the issue you are having is to delete the constraint before you create it

```
ALTER TABLE common.client_contact DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS  client_contact_contact_id_fkey; 

ALTER TABLE common.client_contact
    ADD CONSTRAINT client_contact_contact_id_fkey
    FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES common.contact_item(id)
```

The adding of the named constraint will pass.

Answer (score -12):

I don't know for sure if this will work but you can try it.

Fires, before you do the query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

Then you make the query and

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't even *have* a `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` GUC, so I don't know where you got that one. Second, this isn't about temporarily violating a foreign key (a terrible idea anyway), it's about defining a new foreign key constraint only if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thats I said, "I don't know for sure if this will work but you can try it."