# Hibernate: data.sql causing "already exists" error with PostgreSQL or MysSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use `data.sql` and `schema.sql` files in order to create tables and populate them in a Spring Boot app. However, after first run, when I start the app again, it gives "already exist" error for table, constraints, table values.

I solved the table problem by adding "IF NOT EXISTS", but the others are not so easy. In this situation, should I use H2 instead of PostgreSQL or MySQL so that the database cleared after each run? I know, normally I would prefer Flyway, but for this project, I cannot use it. So, what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Postgres: Add constraint if it doesn't already exist*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6801919/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque No amigo, not duplicate. Please read the question and the answer you suggested, you will probably see the difference. But I will help you; I read that page before opening the question, but even if I solved some part of the problem, I need to solve the problem regarding to the INSERT clauses in my `data.sql`. So, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `IF NOT EXISTS`/`IF EXISTS`

Many commands do offer a `IF NOT EXISTS` clause.

You found that in the `CREATE TABLE` command.

Adding/dropping a column do too, in Postgres. [See documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertable.html).

> ADD [ COLUMN ] [ IF NOT EXISTS ] column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]
>
> DROP [ COLUMN ] [ IF EXISTS ] column_name [ RESTRICT | CASCADE ]

### Drop, then add

Some commands do not support `IF NOT EXISTS`. One of those is adding a constraint. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403384/642706) suggests executing a `DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS` before doing `ADD CONSTRAINT`. This drop-then-add approach may work in some other situations as well.

That other Question also has other Answers with various approaches you may want to consider.

But I expect that for more complicated scenarios, you may need to track whether SQL operations have already been performed.

## *Flyway* for the win

[*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)), [*Liquibase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase), etc. really are the best solution for tracking which SQL scripts have been run and which need to be run.

Otherwise *you* will need to devise a way to track which scripts have been run. I would rather rely on a solution already built & tested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I agree with you and normally I would prefer Flyway. But in have not that option and have to use data.sql. On the other hand, "Drop, then add" does also seem to be a good option as I can drop and re-insert the records.