# Is it possible to rollback create_all in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sql, transactions, sqlalchemy, rollback, ddl

According to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692690/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-create-table-and-alter-table-statements-in-major-sql) question for some DBMSs it is possible to rollback CREATE TABLE statement. 
Particularry it is possible for sqlite (although it is undocumented).

So my question is, is it possible to rollback create_all in sqlalchemy?
I was trying to write some test code, but it seems not to work:

```
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
>>> engine
Engine(sqlite:///:memory:)
>>> Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
>>> connection = engine.connect()
>>> session = Session(bind=connection)
>>> engine.table_names()
[]
>>> transaction = connection.begin()
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> class Test(Base):
...    __tablename__ = 'TEST'
...    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...
>>> Base.metadata.bind = engine
>>> Base.metadata.create_all()
>>> engine.table_names()
[u'TEST']
>>> transaction.rollback()
>>> session.close()
>>> connection.close()
>>> engine.table_names()
[u'TEST']
```

Comment: If you want to do within the **ORM** itself (for test case etc.), check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774899/how-do-you-create-a-table-with-sqlalchemy-within-a-transaction-in-postgres

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use Postgresql or SQL Server.   MySQL, Oracle do *not* support transactional DDL.  Recent versions of SQLite do appear to support transactional DDL.  The Python [sqlite3 driver](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) however [does not](http://bugs.python.org/issue10740).
2. simple recipe:

   ```
   with engine.begin() as conn:
       metadata.create_all(conn)
   ```

   if you raise an exception inside the "with:", the transaction will be rolled back.
3. want to see it yourself, OK:

   ```
   from sqlalchemy import inspect   # need to be running 0.8 for this

   with engine.connect() as conn:
      trans = conn.begin()
      metadata.create_all(conn)
      inspector = inspect(conn)
      table_names = inspector.get_table_names()
      trans.rollback()
      inspector = inspect(conn)
      rolled_back_table_names = inspector.get_table_names()
   ```

to gain an understanding of transactional scope, I recommend you read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be precise I do know that it is possible for engines you have mentioned. As I understand correctly your answer means: it is not possible in SQLAlchemy. (because it IS possible to rollback create table in sqlite client - sqlite3). Is that correct?

Comment: edited.   it's the sqlite3 driver, which has the above mentioned issue as well as other [long unresolved](http://bugs.python.org/issue9924) issues regarding its poor handling of transaction state.