# How do you create a table with Sqlalchemy within a transaction in Postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, ddl, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Sqlalchemy in a multitenant Flask application and need to create tables on the fly when a new tenant is added. I've been using Table.create to create individual tables within a new Postgres schema (along with search_path modifications) and this works quite well.

The limitation I've found is that the Table.create method blocks if there is anything pending in the current transaction. I have to commit the transaction right before the .create call or it will block. It doesn't appear to be blocked in Sqlalchemy because you can't Ctrl-C it. You have to kill the process. So, I'm assuming it's something further down in Postgres.

I've read in other answers that CREATE TABLE is transactional and can be rolled back, so I'm presuming this should be working. I've tried starting a new transaction with the current engine and using that for the table create (vs. the current Flask one) but that hasn't helped either.

Does anybody know how to get this to work without an early commit (and risking partial dangling data)?

This is Python 2.7, Postgres 9.1 and Sqlalchemy 0.8.0b2.

Comment: Just found this answer about DROPs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778942/python-sqlalchemy-postgresql-program-freezes If that is also true for CREATEs, then it doesn't sound like there is a way around this.

Comment: Related FAQ over at Sqlalchemy: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/FAQ#MyprogramishangingwhenIsaytable.dropmetadata.drop_all

Comment: It doesn't look like your `Table.create` is being done in the same transaction. Try triggering the block and check the output of `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: Assuming `sess` is the session, you can do `sess.execute(CreateTable(tenantX_tableY))` instead.

Comment: Sorry, but What do you mean by "triggering the block"? Regardless, I think you are right, but I'm not sure how to get Sqlalchemy to stick the create into my current transaction because it wants a connectable to do it on.

Comment: Bingo! That did the trick. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Great :) Comment copied as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Copy from comment)

<del>Assuming `sess` is the session, you can do `sess.execute(CreateTable(tenantX_tableY))` instead.</del>

EDIT: `CreateTable` is only one of the things being done when calling `table.create()`. Use `table.create(sess.connection())` instead.

Comment: One thing I'm still working on. One of my tables has an enum and CreateTable isn't creating it. Any suggestions on how to handle that?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Hmm.. I have no experience with enum. The project I works on has to support different RDBMS, and enum is something that I would like to use but can't.

Comment: wouldn't you want to be using table.create(sess.connection()) instead?  that will do the ENUM types contained within also.

Comment: @zzzeek Right. I wrongly thought both `sess.execute(CreateTable(table))` and `table.create(sess.connection())` do the same thing, and happen to like the former's syntax better. Turn out `visit_table` does a lot more than just `CreateTable`.

Comment: Well, that's much better and straight from the source. I removed my update about Enum's from the question.