# postgresql: alter multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, psql

My database has severals table with some column type 'money'. I would like to alter all these columns (in different tables) in a single statement rather than change type column by column, to avoid omissions.

Comment: You need one statement per table. There is no way to alter columns from multiple tables in a single statement. It can be done in a single transaction though.

Comment: Ok, how can I do this. (one statement per table)

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: I manage to alter one column in the table, but don't to alter multiple column in the sam table

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to repeat the altering query for every column.
You might want to create a program code to do that for you. You know, with loops.

In order for the database to alter all the tables atomically you should enclose all the altering queries in a transaction (PostgreSQL [supports transactional DDL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4736346/257568)).