# Rollback does not work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using InnoDb engine by default. And this is what looks strange:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set session transaction isolation level serializable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table test_1(id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_reestr |
+------------------+
| test_1          |
+------------------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It looks strange, because I started transaction and rollbacked, but to no avail. So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check: [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html).

Comment: Goodness, what?! Such a long list of statements. It is unbelievable.

Comment: BTW. I've just tested it, that if I add `INSERT` to the table right after `CREATE`, then after rollback I still can see that data was added to the table - contrary to what I wanted to achive. Does it mean that MySQL is so counterintuitive and in fact rubbish??

Comment: You would have to start a new transaction after the `CREATE` and before the `INSERT`, because the previous transaction was committed, and thus, it's over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the comment above: in MySQL, basically all operations that alter database objects perform auto-commit. The main categories are:

1. any DDL on your objects, like `CREATE/ALTER/DROP TABLE/VIEW/INDEX`...,
2. anything that modifies the system database `mysql`, like `ALTER/CREATE USER`,
3. any administrative commands, like `ANALYZE`,
4. any data loading/replication statements.

Actually, I find it best to assume that `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are safe, and anything else is not.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: Thank you! That is absolutely right. I've just checked it and it works like you are saying.

Comment: By the way, it seems like in many other popular databases, the behaviour of transactions is more intuitive.

Comment: Well, that depends. SQL Server, yes - but Oracle behaves very much like MySQL in this case.

Comment: As for Oracle, if I understand it correct from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692690/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-create-table-and-alter-table-statements-in-major-sql - then it behaves in a different manner, than MySQL. At least, modern versions of Oracle.

Comment: Yes and no. By default, modern versions of Oracle (including 11.2 and 12.1) perform implicit commit before all DDL operations, see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4011.htm#SQLRF01110 . "edition-based redefinition" is a bit different and requires some work from the DBA.