# Phinx transaction doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, phinx

Trying to figure out how transaction works at phinx package. Here is my migration code and it doesn't work. I use `mysql` and everything is ok with `phinx.yml`. So table `acme` is created while table `fail` fails and no records are found in `phinxlog` table. So, when I ran `phinx migrate` I've error `SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'acme' already exists`. So, how can I use transactions? I didn't find any docs about it, Help me please))

```
public function up()
{
    $this->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();
    $this->table('acme')->addColumn('name', 'string')->create();
    $this->table('fail')->addColumn('lal', 'failme')->create();
    $this->getAdapter()->commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: all tables have `InnoDB` engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transactions only apply to data (DML) changes with mysql. You cannot 'transact' data definition changes (DDL).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html

But other DBs can (under certain conditions).

[Is it possible to roll back CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements in major SQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692690/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-create-table-and-alter-table-statements-in-major-sql)