# PowerShell MySQL transactions not working

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to get transactions to work using PowerShell and MySQL.  My code is based on https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-some-examples-to-use-a-mysql-database/:

```
[string]$sMySQLUserName = 'user';
[string]$sMySQLPW = 'passw0rd';
[string]$sMySQLDB = 'mydatabase';
[string]$sMySQLHost = localhost';
[string]$sConnectionString = "server="+$sMySQLHost+";port=3306;uid=" + $sMySQLUserName + ";pwd=" + $sMySQLPW + ";database="+$sMySQLDB;

$mySqlTempTableDefinition = 'create table some_temp_table (
    sku varchar(50) primary key,
    thing float null
)';

$oConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($sConnectionString);
$oConnection.Open();

$oMYSQLTransaction=$oConnection.BeginTransaction();
$oMYSQLCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand;
$oMYSQLCommand.Connection=$oConnection;
$oMYSQLCommand.Transaction=$oMYSQLTransaction;
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText = "SET autocommit = 0";
$iRows=$oMYSQLCommand.executeNonQuery();

$oMYSQLCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$oMYSQLCommand.Connection=$oConnection;
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText = $mySqlTempTableDefinition;    
$oMYSQLCommand.Transaction=$oMYSQLTransaction;
$iRows=$oMYSQLCommand.executeNonQuery();

$oMySQLTransaction.Rollback();
$oMySqlCommand.Connection.Close();
```

The first time I run it, the table is created and persisted in the database, which is not the expected result, since I never commit the transaction.  Of course, this means that a subsequent run fails because the table already exists.  How do I correctly implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it as a C# console app, and it didn't work there, either.

It turns out that MySQL does not support DDL in transactions:

[Is it possible to roll back CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements in major SQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692690/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-create-table-and-alter-table-statements-in-major-sql)