# How to rollback all migrations when one migration fails in database migrations TypeORM (NodeJS)

Tags: migration, typeorm

When two or more migrations are run together during the same task (e.g. migrate up or down), and one fails,  only the failed migration is rolled back. I want all the migrations to be rolled back, when one fails.

Example:

```js
export class createRbacs1582769140618 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(
            new Table({
                name: "fake_table",
                columns: [
                    {
                        name: "id",
                        type: "int"
                    }
                ]
            })
        );
        await queryRunner.dropTable("not_exits_table");
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {}
}
```

Although migrations task do not record to the migrations table, **fake_table** still created

Answer (score 0):

According to typeorm [MigrationExecutor](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/migration/MigrationExecutor.ts#L29), typeorm supports transaction in migration as default.

But if you're using mysql, [it can't rollback DDL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692690/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-create-table-and-alter-table-statements-in-major-sql).