# Rollback when doing a database migration with goose

Tags: go, goose

I am using [this](https://github.com/steinbacher/goose) goose flavor. I want my migration script to roll back when there is an error. Wrapping my statements within `-- +goose StatementStart` and `-- +goose StatementEnd` did not work for me.

```
-- +goose Up
-- SQL in section 'Up' is executed when this migration is applied
-- +goose StatementBegin
ALTER TABLE books
    ADD COLUMN author VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL AFTER name;

UPDATE books
SET author = created_by
WHERE created > '2021-01-05';
-- +goose StatementEnd

-- +goose Down
-- SQL section 'Down' is executed when this migration is rolled back
-- +goose StatementBegin
ALTER TABLE books
    DROP COLUMN author;
-- +goose StatementEnd
```

This results in `Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE...`.

Is this possible with goose? Or do I need to write only a single query in one migration file?

Comment: think you should have only one sql statement per pair of begin/end statements. but, that does not seem to do what you think it does https://github.com/steinbacher/goose/blob/dc457c3195032dd1c3848e21dc95ed02c92f8cfa/migration_sql.go#L44 this is more a workaround because sql syntax is hard.

Comment: `I want my migration script to roll back when there is an error.` have you tried it already ?

Comment: you can read here what is going on udner the hood https://github.com/steinbacher/goose/blob/dc457c3195032dd1c3848e21dc95ed02c92f8cfa/migration_sql.go#L137

Comment: finally, this is all closely related to your DB engine https://stackoverflow.com/a/4736346/4466350

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MySQL 5.7 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html), most DDL queries cannot be executed as transactions.

So this should be not possible to done with any workaround since it is tied to underlying database type and version.

[@mh-cbon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466350/mh-cbon) thank you you for pointing out that.