# Rollback complex transaction with create table in the end

Tags: mysql, spring

Using Spring Boot 2.5.4 and MySQL.

I have a function which has the @Transactional() annotation.
Inside, I update some entities and use

```
myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
```

Afterwards, I use an EntityManager.createNativeQuery() in which I create a new table:

```
String cr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + projectId +
                "TABLE DESCRIPTION";

entityManager.createNativeQuery(cr).executeUpdate();
```

After this I have to call an external server (authentication keycloak server) to create a resource there as well.
If this does not work, I throw an exception.
I expected the whole transaction to rollback, which it did not.
I then read about create table having its internal commit (e.g. here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html ,
[Is it possible to roll back CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements in major SQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692690/is-it-possible-to-roll-back-create-table-and-alter-table-statements-in-major-sql)) and that it is not possible to rollback with MySQL.

When I remove the create table code (entityManager.createNativeQuery(cr).executeUpdate();) everything else is rolled back when the exception is thrown. (Just for me to make sure it generally works).

My question:
Is there a good solution to fix this? To cleanly roll back everything without me doing it by hand? Possibly with MySQL? Of course, I can drop the table manually, but I'd rather prefer to have everything else rolled back by Spring instead of me.

Any help is appreciated.
Please note: I have not posted any pom.xml, properties, source code, as I think these information just bloat this post up, instead of being helpful. Of course, if needed, I add more to this.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some reading, I will convert my database to PostgreSQL